# New to Visual FoxPro- my textboxes are greyed out and inaccessible

Tags: textbox, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm attempting to create a Visual FoxPro standalone application that will take two inputs from a user (old location and new location). It will have two tables with a 1:M relationship with primary and foreign keys matching the old location.  The application should then replace all instances in both tables of the old location with the new location.

I've put the form together and got the fields in both tables displaying in grids, both textboxes present and an "Update Records" submit button.

My problem is that my textboxes are greyed out when I select "Form">"Run Form" and I can't input anything.

Does anyone have any ideas why the boxes would be greyed out?  I checked in Properties > Data > Read only and they are both marked as .F.

Thanks so much for your help!

*edit:  Figured it out- Had ControlSource on because I thought that would bind the input to a specific field in a specific table.  Never mind!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out- Had ControlSource on because I thought that would bind the input to a specific field in a specific table.  Never mind!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Kate

Just as an aside. the text boxes can be greyed out for a number of reasons, the most obvious ones are property set to readonly = .t. or enabled = .f., but also if the text box is bound to a datasource and that source is not available.

i.e the table EMPTY or is EOF() or BOF()